# cpuminer-multi error when mining cryptonight on Linux

Tags: cryptonight, raspberry-pi, bytecoin

I have just set up cpuminer-multi on my Raspberry Pi B+, my aim is to mine a cryptonight coin called Bytecoin. Instead of connecting the mining Pi to the pool, I will be connecting the mining Pi to a proxy which is connected to the pool, so that I can mine with more than one Pi.

I did this by doing the following...

```
# update raspbian
sudo apt-get update -y

# install the following dependent modules
sudo apt-get install autoconf libcurl4-openssl-dev libjansson-dev openssl libssl-dev gcc gawk

# clone this miner repo
git clone https://github.com/lucasjones/cpuminer-multi.git

# navigate to the directory and compile
cd cpuminer-multi
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

But When I enter the following code to start the miner...

```
 ./minerd -a cryptonight -o pool.bytecoin.party:3333 -u (My Bytecoin Address Was Here) -t 1
```

I get the following error...

```
[2018-01-08 21:40:07] Using JSON-RPC 2.0
[2018-01-08 21:40:07] CPU Supports AES-NI: NO
[2018-01-08 21:40:07] 1 miner threads started, using 'cryptonight' algorithm.
[2018-01-08 21:40:07] HTTP request failed: Empty reply from server
[2018-01-08 21:40:07] getwork failed, retry after 10 seconds
```

I have even tried setting up a proxy on another Raspberry Pi that connects to the pool, but when I try to connect the mining Raspberry Pi to the proxy Raspberry Pi, I get the same error.

I tried to see if the miner will mine any other cryptocurrencies, so I initiated scrypt mining to my Litecoin pool and that worked well.

I am unsure about how to fix this, any help or suggestions will be much appreciated,

Thanks!

Sid

Comment: While I'm not trying to dissuade you from `bytecoin` per se, make sure you are familiar with the asserted background that the devs premined 82% of the coins in advance. It is one of the reasons `Monero` is such a success and many of the active enthusiasts abandoned `bytecoin`. Do a little reading then make your own decision of course. Here's a reference: https://www.ccn.com/bytecoin-original-anonymous-cryptocurrency-jumps-250-comeback/

Answer (score 1):

Your pool uses the stratum protocol instead of the older getwork protocol that cpuminer-multi defaults to. Use `-o stratum+tcp://pool.bytecoin.party:3333`.

I'd also recommend switching to [xmrig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig) since cpuminer-multi has been dead for a while.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your mining-pool. I recommend to try another pool. Take a look at [Coinfoundry](https://coinfoundry.org). Fee is 0.15% and other then that you don't need to pay anything else.

The URL is: `xmr.coinfoundry.org:3032`

And please use [xmrig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig) instead of `minerd`

BTW: If you are mining on an raspberry pi, don't mine Monero. Not even slightly enough hashing power. Take a look at mining Electroneum (ETN). Coinfoundry has a pool for that also.